# Can't use fingerprint scanner in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, thinkpad, scanner, fingerprint-reader

I have a Lenovo L490, with a built-in fingerprint scanner (27c6:55b4  Shenzen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader). I'm on ubuntu 20.04, and when I try to setup the fingerprint scanner for login, I get the error message: "Could not access any fingerprint readers. Please contact your system administrator for help.". Even though my account is the only one on this device. When I had ubuntu 28.04 I tried using fingerprint-gui, which could never find my fingerprint scanner.
Any help?

Comment: Is your device [supported](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html) by libfprint?

Comment: it's not on that list. are those the only ones supported?

Comment: There's a mailing list, please try that https://fprint.freedesktop.org/